# Sum of terms in a multinomial expansion? (that is all coefficients are equal to one)

Tags: sequences-and-series, multinomial-coefficients

How to sum the series $a^3+b^3+c^3+a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b+abc$?

And in general for any multinomial expansion.

Comment: To sum it you can add the terms...?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio the sum of the powers is n for any term.

Comment: @LinusS. we can do that, but I am looking for a formula which will minimize the sequence.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry I will have to update my question. However coefficients are always one. And thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Are you trying to minimize the number of times you perform addition?

Comment: @LinusS. Its more like I want to reduce number of operations in general.

Comment: Your comments have changed the question so much that you should edit the question into an clear, understandable, final form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is want you are looking for:
$$\sum_{\substack{0\leq i,j,k\leq 3\\i+j+k =3}}a^ib^jc^k = [x^3]\left(\frac{1}{1-ax}\cdot\frac{1}{1-bx}\cdot\frac{1}{1-cx}\right)\tag{1}$$
hence in order to find your sum you may differentiate $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-ax)(1-bx)(1-cx)}$ three times, evaluate in zero and divide by $3!=6$:
$$ \sum_{\substack{0\leq i,j,k\leq 3\\i+j+k =3}}a^ib^jc^k = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{f(3\varepsilon)-3f(2\varepsilon)+3f(\varepsilon)-f(0)}{6\varepsilon^3}\tag{2} $$
If you know in advance that $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$, to compute your sum you just have to take a small $\varepsilon$ and approximate the RHS of $(2)$ to the closest integer.

Comment: I believe this is the solution I am looking for. Can you kindly provide source or pointer to the solution? And thanks a lot

Comment: @Baruntar: have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomial

Answer (score 0):

This specific one can be simplified to

$(a+b+c)^3 - 2(a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b) - 5abc = (a+b+c)^3 - 2(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) - abc$

I picked this specific factorization because after calculating $a+b+c$, the sums $a+b$, $a+c$, and $b+c$ all come quickly. However, I do not know of a generalized "fastest" algorithm to generate the minimum number of computations.

There are definitely algorithms to do this, though as far as I know they do not reduce this completely in every case. Restricting the coefficients to one actually hurts rather than helps in this case, since the symmetric expressions easiest to produce generally have coefficients. This comes from the fact that taking any elementary symmetric polynomial to a power generates coefficients.

Comment: Factoring was the first thing I thought about, but generalizing was bit tedious. Right now I am looking into solution provided by @Jack D'Aurizio